# How to ask colleague to stop singing under their breath in the office?

Tags: colleagues, distractions

I have a colleague who sings under their breath while working. It's quite disturbing, even with headphones on. How can I assertively request that they stop doing it without coming across as controlling?

Comment: @TheSnarkKnight Don't Worry, Be Happy is better.  Every time you hear him hum just start singing that and it'll never leave his head.  It's passive-aggression on steroids. :)

Comment: similar to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104474/how-to-tell-office-colleague-to-turn-off-radio See that question for my response re: humming colleague. Also see https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/what-can-i-do-about-a-very-loud-coworker

Comment: You could always hire  John McClane to have a "talk" with him...

Answer (score 7):

Every suggestion here seems to be jokingly passive aggressive. I'm not sure that's really warranted and the singer may be doing it unconsciously or thinks he is unheard. As a hummer myself, I would prefer someone simply says to me:

> "Hey Forklift, sorry to interrupt you, but that singing is a little bit distracting for me. Do you think you could listen to music on your headphones instead?"